# Criminals/hackers trick computer system into backing up all data into single location

Tags: identify-this-movie

I would like help identifying this movie, the plot of the movie goes as follows:

The baddy used to work for a company (possibly US gov. agency) where he helped program their computer system. He knew that in an event of a cyber attack or breach that the system would begin to back up its data into a single location. From there they could perform the real heist.

Sorry I don't know the who's, where or whys, if I did I'm pretty sure I would be able to find it using Google. Hopefully this sounds familiar to someone.

I can barely remember the movie but if I had to guess, I would say it was made between 2000-2012, I don't remember the technology to be partially dated.

Unfortunately no actors are coming to mind, but it was an American action movie.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is pretty much the scheme of [Die Hard 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_Free_or_Die_Hard)'s villain Thomas Gabriel who orchestrates an all-out cyber attack in order to then hack into the USA's entire collective wealth, all located in one place.

> Farrell takes McClane to fellow hacker Frederick "Warlock" Kaludis (Kevin Smith). Running his computer systems from several generators, Warlock identifies the piece of code Farrell wrote as a means to access data at a master Social Security Administration building at Woodlawn, Maryland. They realize the building is actually a **NSA facility intended to backup the nation's entire personal and financial records in the event of a cyber attack, designed by Gabriel himself when he worked for the NSA.**

It was released in 2007. Here's the trailer:

Comment: And now I have to go on a Die Hard binge again...

Comment: Wasn't this the one where McLane fights a fighter jet with his bare hands and wins?  I love that scene.

Comment: He was barefoot too!

Comment: BTW, [this question's timing is spooky](http://www.slate.com/blogs/future_tense/2016/10/21/the_east_coast_cyberattack_what_we_know_now.html)... :) [IIRC, it started in the East Coast in DH4 too]

Comment: start the backup only *after* a cyber-attack is under way?  that's the most ridiculous thing i've ever heard.  oh wait, wrong SE.